# Spark SQL version of EXEC()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Does anyone know of a way in Spark SQL to execute a string variable like the following?

```
INSERT TableA (Col1,Col2) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM TableB
```

I understand that I can obviously write this statement directly. However, I am using a work flow engine where my Insert/Select statement is in String variable. If not, I assume I should use spark_submit. I was looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what environment you're in. If this is a Spark application or a Spark shell you always provide queries as strings:

```
val query = "INSERT TableA (Col1,Col2) SELECT Col1,Col2 FROM TableB"
sqlContext.sql(query)
```

*(See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically.)*

Answer (score -2):

Spark Sql also support hive queries

```
insert overwrite table usautomobiles select * from sourcedata
```

Go Through this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL)

Comment: How does this solve the problem of executing a query stored in a variable?