# I am running below code to run SQL procedure through Spark JDBC in python

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I am running below code to run SQL procedure through Spark JDBC in python and getting error.

> Parse error at line: 1, column: 15: Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'.

Means some syntax error while executing EXEC [jarvis].[uspGetCreditOutputLatestTimeStampForGamification]. Can you please help me with correct code to call sql procedure thoiugh spark jdbc in pyspark?

[image]

I tried different sytax but did't worked, I am expecting right code to call sql stored procedure       through Spark JDBC.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create a SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Run SQL Procedure using JDBC").getOrCreate()

# set the JDBC connection properties
jdbcHostname = "--"
jdbcPort = "--"
jdbcDatabase = "--"
jdbcUsername = "--"
jdbcPassword = "--"

jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2}".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase)
connectionProperties = {
  "user": jdbcUsername,
  "password": jdbcPassword,
  "driver": "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}

# specify the name of the SQL procedure and its parameters
procedureName = "[jarvis].[uspGetCreditOutputLatestTimeStampForGamification]"
param1 = "DeltaLoad"
#param2 = "<param2>"
#EXEC  @resultVal = [dbo].[uspGetEmployeeRosterAssignmentToTERA]

# build the SQL query string
query = "EXEC {0} @param1='{1}' ".format(procedureName, param1)
print(query)

# read the result of the procedure into a DataFrame
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=query, properties=connectionProperties)

# show the DataFrame
df.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please replace the query with the following statement and retry:

```
query = f"EXEC {procedureName} @param1='{param1}'"
```

or

```
query = f"EXEC [{procedureName}] @param1='{param1}'"
```

Also try putting the schema name in front of the procedure name

```
query = f"EXEC [schema_name].[{procedureName}] @param1='{param1}'"
```

Comment: still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

`spark` will accept queries in Spark's SQL syntax. Spark parses that SQL and translates it before it's sent to the actual DB. So in this case (`spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, table=query, ...`) content of `query` needs to use [Spark SQL](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref.html) syntax. And Spark SQL has no `EXEC` command.

If you just want to execute some random SQL (in some DB specific SQL syntax) on some random DB over a JDBC connection, use a python jdbc module like [pyjdbc](https://pypi.org/project/pyjdbc/) or [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/) or [MySQL-python](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) or [cx-Oracle](https://pypi.org/project/cx-Oracle/). That's non-spark code. Think of running some GRANT statements or invoking some stored procedure etc.

You would want to use `spark.read.jdbc()` to [read from RDB](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) only if you want to use it as a data source to read efficiently (upper/lower-Bound/numPartitions), create Dataframes and do "spark things" with that data.

---

Also note sure if it's relevant but check out: [Spark SQL version of EXEC()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34220792/spark-sql-version-of-exec)